# How to combine sublist and string to list in python

Tags: python

I am trying to combine list and strings to list
such as

```
[['hello', 'stack', 'over'], 'flow', 'i', 'have', [], 'question']
```

to

```
['hello', 'stack', 'over', 'flow', 'i', 'have', 'question']
```

How to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Comment: it does not because it aasssumes its a 2d array unconditionally...